# How to change the texture of the wall of a 3D model like gITF, glb, fbx etc. using drop down choice in Threejs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js

I have a Threejs app in which I render various 3d models like gItf, fbx, glb etc. I need help in changing the texture of a particular mesh on a click event and apply the texture that user has selected from a dropdown. I need help in doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture can be applied to the material through `map` property.

`mesh.material.map = new TextureLoader().load('<image url to the texture or base64>')`

where mesh being the gltf/fbx/glb model object from the scene object or any sub mesh within the model object

Try to reuse the TextureLoader object

If you log your scene object, it should have children array which contains lights, camera, the 3d model and the other objects you create in the scene.

The 3d model object can in turn have children array each child representing a mesh(depends on how it was created). You can choose which mesh you want the texture to be applied to. Hope this helps!